# How is turbine engine oil pressure associated with turbine engine speed?

Tags: turbine

I've seen scenarios where engine oil pressure can be used to indicate if turbine engines are performing correctly at intended speed.

How exactly is this associated?

I'm not certain, but if I had to guess; the EDP (engine driven pump) from engine startup would eventually increase flow rate of engine oil as the engine speed increases, thus more flow to the pressure regulator which increases oil pressure?

Comment: On all the turbine engines that I have operated, the oil pressure comes up quickly as the engine spools up and then remains at a regulated pressure regardless of engine speed. The same is generally true for reciprocating designs. Oil pressure systems incorporate pressure regulators that keep oil pressure at proper levels throughout the operating range of the engine. There is little or no correlation between oil pressure and engine speed. Could you clarify or explain what you are asking about?

Comment: You've answered it, I was trying to figure out if there was a correlation between engine speed, and engine oil pressure.